# Корни слов: "пошлость" и "пошлина"

Tags: этимология

Являются ли слова "пошлость" и "пошлина" однокоренными и, если да, то почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, слова родственны, правда на древнем уровне. 
"Почему?" - это немного странный вопрос. Так уж получилось. 
Если вас интересует, *почему так считают*, т.е. этимологическое обоснование, то всё очень просто. И там и там исторический корень тот же, что и в слове "шел".

*Пошлый* исходно - старинный, древний, исконный.
*Пошлина* (по Фасмеру) - "чьто пошьло есть", т.е. тоже восходит к "исконный", "прежний".

Answer (score 1):

Я так полагаю . **ПОШЛОСТЬ** в древнем первоначальном  смысле означала **простоту** , **обычность** , **заурядность** . Например , царь Иван Грозный в одном из своих посланий называл английскую королеву Елизавету "девкой **пошлой**" , и при этом имелось в виду не её *облико морало* , а её непосредственное участие в торговых делах ; то есть , как **простая** девка . А вот **ПОШЛИНА** связана не с *пошлостью* , а с **посулом** , - **посул** , **посулить** , **сулить** . "Полный церковно-славянский словарь" магистра Григория Дьяченко стр. 466 (интернет-ссылка [link text](http://www.slavdict.narod.ru/_0466.htm) ) сообщает : "**Посулъ = обещанiе , взятка .(Собр. госуд. грам. 1426 г. т. I , стр. 24)**" . И "*взятка*" здесь употребляется не как *коррупционное деяние* , а как вполне законный , легальный сбор , мзда , платёж . То есть , под понятием **ПОШЛИНА** подразумевается **заранее обещанная , оговоренная  плата** .

Answer (score 1):

Да это нормальна фраза, не будете платить-- пошли на....с конкретной адресацией, куда. А  тем, которым не хочется, в силу ограниченности кругозора и МОНАШЕской косности(им же адресат в полной запретке==табу, они вместо этого херъ придумали, что тоже не в тему, слишком много оттуда корешков полезло) стали называть посыл--пошлостью, как и вообще мат, матерный говор--родная речь--по-сербски, язык хранит историю, как бы ни изгалялись ИЕ-старатели.
анализ выводит на чистую воду всю историю от фонаря и этимологию от фасмеров.

Answer (score 0):

*ПоШЛый* = *расХОЖий*, и далее *избитый*, *затасканный* (Расхожее мнение, избитая истина, затасканная, например, рифма). Нечто шлялось, шлялось и порядком поистаскалось. *Опошлилось*.

*Пошлина* - плата за то, чтоб пройти в определённом месте. Плати - и пошел. )))))

Answer (score 0):

Устаревшее значение слова "пошлость" — старина, старинный обычай. Очень похоже, что пошлость=прошлость с исчезнувшей Р. В английском тоже есть похожее слово posh, которое означает старинный аристократический выговор.

Comment: Вовсе не выговор, а что угодно. Это прилагательное. И как Вы всё это связываете: аристократический, пошлое, и прошлое?

Comment: Неужели связь между аристократией и стариной не очевидна? Аристократ тем значительнее чем древнее его род, а английская аристократия особенно подчеркивает свою древность. В силу различий исторического развития, у нас слово п(р)ошлость приняло негативный оттенок, а в английском слово posh еще сохраняет позитивный, хотя posh акцент уже многими воспринимается как чудачество.