# Пошлось — этимология

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

А каково происхождение слова "пошлость"? Слова "пошли" (в смысле "пойдемте") и "пошлить" — однокоренные?

Comment: По-моему, об этом недавно уже говорили здесь, поищите

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я думаю, что приведенный ниже текст даст Вам полный ответ.
Этимология слова пошлость

Происходит от древнерусского пошьлъ «старинный, исконный; прежний, обычный». 
Ср. знач. нем. gemein «общий, всеобщий; низкий, подлый». Из походить, пошел.

"В. Даль. Толковый словарь живого великорусского языка"
«Пошлость» – слово исконно русское, которое коренится в глаголе «пошли».

До XVII века оно употреблялось в более чем благопристойном значении и означало все привычное, традиционное, совершаемое по обычаю, то, что ПОШЛО исстари.

Филолог В. Виноградов приводит следующие строки из рукописей конца XIV века: 
«А мыты ны держати давныи пошлыи, а непошлыхъ мытовъ и пошлинъ не замышляти»; 
«Пожаловалъ есми... деревнею Куколцинымъ и съ лъсомъ и съ пожнями, куды топоръ ходилъ, куды коса ходила, съ пошлою землею, что къ неи из старины тянуло». 
Или пример из В. Даля: «А ездоки ездят не пошлою дорогою».

Однако в конце XVII – начале XVIII веков начались Петровские реформы, прорубка окна в Европу и борьба со всеми древними «пошлыми» обычаями.

Слово «пошлый» стало на глазах терять уважение и теперь всё больше значило – «отсталый», «постылый», «некультурный», «простоватый». Вскоре «пошлостью» стали чаще называть тривиальность, банальность, ограниченность. Пошлая шутка – значит заезженная и ныне неприличная.

«Пошлый – избитый, общеизвестный, надокучивший, …неприличный».

К середине XIX века уже появились и такие слова, как «пошляк», «пошлячка», «опошлить», а пошлость стала неразлучным синонимом мещанства – еще одного безобидного слова, ставшего негативным.

Answer (score 2):

Конечно, [говорили](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2848/%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Не закрываю только потому, что жаль терять ответ. На усмотрение модераторов.

ЗЫ Слова "пошлость" и "пошёл"  не только однокоренные, но едва ли не непосредственно одно другое породившие. Пошлость - исходно то, что обыденно, привычно, что **ходит между людьми**

Comment: Вот и не закрывайте. Здесь для этого есть администрация.

Comment: @Fuchoin Kazuki, это касается только конкретного вопроса, или как общее правило?

Comment: Посмотрела справку: она сильно изменилась. Раньше говорилось, что эти форумы - "совместно редактируемые", теперь это свойство не вынесено на первый план. Хотя сами возможности (в том числе удалять) у участников остались.